# Cannot display variable labels in finalfit.coxph results

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm doing survival analysis in R and RMarkdown to display my tables. I've assigned labels to the variables in question using var_label from the labelled package. When I pass the results of finalfit.coxph to a .rda file and load it into my RMarkdown document, it prints the table with the full variable name.

I've tried modifying it with a print() function which has worked with different functions (tableOne, for example) to no avail.

Here is how I'm creating this table.

```r
  dependent <- "Surv(DX_LASTCONTACT_DEATH_MONTHS, RECODED_STATUS)"
  explanatory <-
    as.factor(c(
      "AGE_GROUP",
      "SEX",
      "FACILITY_TYPE_CD",
      "PRIMARY_SITE",
      "URBAN_RURAL",
      "CDCC_SHORT",
      "GRADE_RECODE",
      "SURGERY_MARGINS",
      "ANY_RADIATION",
      "ANY_CHEMO"
    ))
  coxTable <-
    finalfit.coxph(allMucoEpi, dependent = dependent, explanatory = explanatory, metrics = TRUE)
```

I've tried modifying it to use the following

```r
      coxTablePrint <-
  print(
    coxTable,
    exact = "stage",
    quote = FALSE,
    noSpaces = TRUE,
    printToggle = FALSE,
    row.names = FALSE,
    test = TRUE,
    showAllLevels = FALSE,
    missing = FALSE,
    varLabels = TRUE
  )
```

But the full variable name persists.

This is the code block in the RMarkdown document.

```
# kable(coxTable, caption = "Multivariate Cox Hazards Analysis",row.names = FALSE,
#     align = c("l", "l", "r", "r", "r"),
#     font_size = 8)

kable(coxTablePrint, "latex", caption = "Multivariate Cox Analysis", row.names = F, booktabs = T)%>%
kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "scale_down", "HOLD_position"), font_size = 7)
```

Here is what I'm currently seeing in the final PDF:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXKEJ.jpg

Here is an example of what I would like to see:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXKEJ.jpg

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Turns out when factors are modified in some way (dropping levels, for example), it clears the label. Resetting the var_label() fixes it for display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out when factors are modified in some way (dropping levels, for example), it clears the label. Resetting the var_label() fixes it for display.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Untested. 
Lots of examples here: 
https://finalfit.org/articles/all_tables_examples.html

```
library(finalfit)
library(dplyr)
dependent <- "Surv(DX_LASTCONTACT_DEATH_MONTHS, RECODED_STATUS)"
# no as.factor here
explanatory <- c(
      "AGE_GROUP",
      "SEX",
      "FACILITY_TYPE_CD",
      "PRIMARY_SITE",
      "URBAN_RURAL",
      "CDCC_SHORT",
      "GRADE_RECODE",
      "SURGERY_MARGINS",
      "ANY_RADIATION",
      "ANY_CHEMO"
    )

allMucoEpi <- allMucoEpi %>%
  mutate(
    AGE_GROUP = factor(AGE_GROUP) %>%
      ff_label(“Age (years)”
    # all other var changes and labels here
    )


allMucoEpi %>%
    finalfit(dependent, explanatory, add_dependent_label = FALSE) %>% 
    dplyr::rename("Death (months)" = label) %>% 
    dplyr::rename(" " = levels) -> coxTable

  coxTable
```